# setting file attributes in cent OS 6.5

Tags: file, attributes, centos

I have a situation, where I have a file named testfile in one partition and when I try using following command

setfattr -n user.comment -v "3.3.3.10" testfile

I am getting this error

setfattr: testfile: Operation not supported

But I am able to set the attribute in all other partitions like /, /boot, /tmp etc.

do I need to enable anything?
please give me a solution. I am using CentOS 6.5.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the partition it's not working on is using a filesystem that don't support extended attributes?

http://linux.die.net/man/5/attr

I think ext2 and ext3 needs the `user_xattr` mount option.